# Unfortunately app has stopped in Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-activity

I run my app on the emulator and when I click on the button for Clubs it just crashes and gives the message "Unfortunately app has stopped in Android Emulator". I've looked at the logcat and it says to check its declared in the manifest file which it is. So I'm just not sure what do. I'll put up my code for the layout file, the java file and the manifest file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/school_icon"
        android:layout_width="206dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_socities"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#CC0000"
        android:text="@string/socities_info" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ace"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ace_icon"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Ace Society"
                    android:textColor="#CC0000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ace_icon"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ace" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ace_fb"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ace"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/anime_manga"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/anime_manga_icon"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Anime Manga"
                    android:textColor="#CC0000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/anime_manga_icon"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/anime_manga" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/anime_manga_fb"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/anime_manga"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/best_buddies"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/best_buddies_icon"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Best Buddies"
                    android:textColor="#CC0000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/best_buddies_icon"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/best_buddies" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/best_buddies_fb"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/best_buddies"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/computer_society"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/computer_society_icon"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Computer Society"
                    android:textColor="#CC0000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/computer_society_icon"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/computer_socity" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/computer_society_fb"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/computer_society"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cumann_gaelach"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cumann_gaelach_icon"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Cumann Gaelach"
                    android:textColor="#CC0000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cumann_gaelach_icon"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/cumann_gaelach" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/cumann_gaelach_fb"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cumann_gaelach"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                </RelativeLayout>               

                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dj_society"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dj_society_icon"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="DJ Society"
                    android:textColor="#CC0000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dj_society_icon"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/dj_society" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/dj_society_fb"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dj_society"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                </RelativeLayout>                   

                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eng_society"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eng_society_icon"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Engineering Society"
                    android:textColor="#CC0000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/eng_society_icon"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/eng_society" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/eng_society_fb"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eng_society"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                </RelativeLayout>   

                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/equestrain"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/equestrain_icon"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Equestrain"
                    android:textColor="#CC0000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/equestrain_icon"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/equestrian" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/equestrain_fb"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/equestrain"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                </RelativeLayout>   

                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fianna_fail"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fianna_fail_icon"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Fianna Fail"
                    android:textColor="#CC0000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fianna_fail_icon"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/fianna_fail" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/fianna_fail_fb"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fianna_fail"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                </RelativeLayout>   

                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/film_society"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/film_society_icon"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="Film Society"
                    android:textColor="#CC0000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/film_society_icon"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/film_society" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/film_society_fb"
                    android:layout_width="206dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/film_society"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                </RelativeLayout>   

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Java file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Clubs extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.socities);

        Button aces = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ace_fb);
        Button anime_manga = (Button) findViewById(R.id.anime_manga_fb);
        Button best_buddies = (Button) findViewById(R.id.best_buddies_fb);
        Button computer_society = (Button) findViewById(R.id.computer_society_fb);
        Button cumann_gaelach = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cumann_gaelach_fb);
        Button dj_society = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dj_society_fb);
        Button eng_society = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eng_society_fb);
        Button equestrian = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equestrain_fb);
        Button fianna_fail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fianna_fail_fb);
        Button film_society = (Button) findViewById(R.id.film_society_fb);
        Button foiroige = (Button) findViewById(R.id.foiroige_fb);
        Button games = (Button) findViewById(R.id.games_fb);
        Button wish_makers_on_campus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wish_makers_on_campus_fb);
        Button heritage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.heritage_fb);
        Button internationl_society = (Button) findViewById(R.id.internationl_society_fb);
        Button letterfrack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.letterfrack_fb);
        Button lgbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lgbt_fb);
        Button living_history = (Button) findViewById(R.id.living_history_fb);
        Button mature_students = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mature_students_fb);
        Button photography = (Button) findViewById(R.id.photography_fb);
        Button robotics = (Button) findViewById(R.id.robotics_fb);
        Button science = (Button) findViewById(R.id.science_fb);
        Button sinnfein = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sinnfein_fb);

        aces.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/aceofclubsgmit?fref=ts"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
            }
        });

        anime_manga.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/gmitanimemangasoc"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
            }
        });


        best_buddies.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/pages/Best-Buddies-GMIT/305305566158422?fref=ts"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
            }
        });

        computer_society.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/GMITComputerSociety"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
            }
        });

        cumann_gaelach.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/gmitcumannnagaeilge?fref=ts"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
            }
        });

        dj_society.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/GmitDjSociety"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
            }
        });

        eng_society.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/pages/EngSoc-GMIT/196642613742557"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
            }
        });

        equestrian.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/gmit.ridingclub"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
            }
        });

        fianna_fail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/sean.mulroycumann"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
            }
        });

        film_society.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/pages/GMIT-Film-Making-Society/1376699195883960?fref=ts"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

============================================================================
Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ie.gmit.pleasework"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="ie.gmit.pleasework.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ie.gmit.pleasework.Sponsors"
            android:label="@string/airsoft" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ie.gmit.pleasework.Societies"
            android:label="@string/airsoft" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ie.gmit.pleasework.Clubs"
            android:label="@string/airsoft" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

=================================================================================
logcat

```
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642): Process: ie.gmit.pleasework, PID: 1642
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {ie.gmit.pleasework/ie.gmit.pleasework.Societies}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at ie.gmit.pleasework.MainActivity$8.onClick(MainActivity.java:101)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-29 11:50:28.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1642):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button contact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContact);
        Button fixturesAndResults = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFixtureandResults);
        Button newsFeed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewsFeed);
        Button sponsors = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSponsors);
        Button scholarships = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScholarships);
        Button facilites = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFacilities);
        Button clubs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClubs);
        Button societies = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSocieties);
        Button about = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);

        contact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Contact.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        fixturesAndResults.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), FixturesAndResults.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        newsFeed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), NewsFeed.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        sponsors.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Sponsors.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        scholarships.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Scholarships.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        facilites.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Facilites.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        clubs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Clubs.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        societies.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Societies.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        about.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), About.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

}

Comment: post your logcat, not your interpretation of what the error is

Comment: Yeah just forgot to put it up with all the other stuff I was trying to get on. Its up now. Thanks

Comment: Post your MainActivity code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared your Activities incorrectly in your manifest.

You wrote, for instance

```
<activity
        android:name="ie.gmit.pleasework.Societies"
        android:label="@string/airsoft" >
    </activity>
```

and should have put

```
<activity
        android:name=".Societies"
        android:label="@string/airsoft" >
    </activity>
```

The names of the classes are taken to be from the root of your application (`ie.gmit.pleasework`). By writing your complete package twice, you're asking Dalvik to find the class `ie.gmit.pleasework/ie.gmit.pleasework.Societies`

Comment: So just leave out the package name altogether, it works when I click the Sponsors button though?

Comment: Overall, by writing .Societies (for instance) you're telling Dalvik to look in the root package of your app's overall package (in this case you're telling it to look for the ie.gmit.pleasework.Societies class). I don't know what you mean by your Sponsors button; it doesn't seem to appear in the code you added to your question.

Comment: Ok so I changed that and now the new entry in logcat says 
04-29 20:28:07.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1144): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ie.gmit.pleasework/ie.gmit.pleasework.Societies}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Comment: Great after getting it working. Just changed all my instances of Button to ImageButton. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it